# How to Dynamically bind an image from my backend server

Tags: image, express, vue.js, path, vuex

I am currently using Vue js and trying to dynamically bind images that I'm getting from my database. I'm getting my path but the images aren't showing up. My front end is on localhost:8080 and my back end on localhost:3000.

In my app.js file, I'm establishing the the public folder as the static directory,
inside that folder I have my uploads directory which is where my images are being sent to.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

I'm sending my images there through multer:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname)
  }
})
```

This is an example of how I'm seeing the image's source code popping up on the inspector.

```
src="public/uploads/2020-03-27T12:16:43.535Zaaa.jpeg"
```

I want to be able to display them dynamically in my components, but the images aren't showing up.
I'm also using Vuex and storing them in an object inside my states.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should access your image using the full address

```
src="http://localhost:3000/uploads/2020-03-27T12:16:43.535Zaaa.jpeg"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I guess I wasn't adding the http and that's what was wrong. Any idea how I can later use this in production?

Comment: If you deploy your front end and back end on the same server, probably you can just use "/uploads/image.jpg", but if you deploy them on two separate servers then you need to use full address "http://yourserver.com/uploads/image.jpg"